# SQL Server script syntax errors and "must declare the scalar value"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a script in T-SQL to resolve a critical issue on our system.  Unfortunately I have never done this before so I'm entering uncharted waters.

I'm actually writing a PHP script to generate this SQL. If the user exists, create it. But in both cases, add the user to a group.

```
DECLARE @userId AS int

/* --------------- 123l123123fvsdf - Name --------------- */
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user] WHERE username = '123l123123fvsdf')
                INSERT INTO [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user](username, password, email, firstname, lastname, created) VALUES('123l123123fvsdf', 'PASSWORD', 'aa00043@user.com', 'firstName', 'lastName', GETDATE())
                GO
                SET @userId = @@IDENTITY
        ELSE
                SET @userId = SELECT id FROM [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user] WHERE username = 'AA00043'
    END
    INSERT INTO [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user_group](user_id, group_id) VALUES(@userId, '7')
```

I'm getting these errors:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@userId".
>
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
>
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@userId".*

I've done some googling on the scalar value and it can happen when my query returns multiple rows, which I've verified that it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to fix your if statement. try:

```
DECLARE @userId AS int

IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user] WHERE username = '123l123123fvsdf')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user](username, password, email, firstname, lastname, created) VALUES('123l123123fvsdf', 'PASSWORD', 'aa00043@user.com', 'firstName', 'lastName', GETDATE())
    SET @userId = @@IDENTITY
END
ELSE
   SET @userId = SELECT id FROM [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user] WHERE username = 'AA00043'

INSERT INTO [CMT_UAT].[dbo].[user_group](user_id, group_id) VALUES(@userId, '7')
```

you have multipl statements in the first part of your if block but you forgot to put `BEGIN` and `END` around it

And also like RBarryYoung pointed out you need to take the `GO` out

Comment: Good call, that helped.  It still doesn't like the syntax near `SELECT`

Comment: Got it, needed to be within parenthesis

Answer (score 5):

Take the "GO" out of your script. "GO" is a provider instruction that tells the connect manager to end the execution batch and to start a new one. Thus, it's resetting your execution context , wiping out your `@userid` variable declaration.